# How to retrieve Image via link in an Object?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am using Vue JS to create a web application.

I convert the object into a JSON, however, the link that is used to retrieve the image only comes up as a string, which I am aware of what the JSON conversion does.

Is there a way for the link to bring the image through? Maybe I am missing something when I am doing the conversion to JSON?

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      baby: [

        {
          id: "botamon",
          name: "Botamon",
          stage: "Baby",
          type: "Data",
          digivolution: ["Koromon"],
          image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg"
        },

        {
          id: "poyomon",
          name: "Poyomon",
          stage: "Baby",
          type: "Data",
          digivolution: ["tokomon"],
          image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/86-poyomon.jpg"
        },

        {
          id: "punimon",
          name: "Punimon",
          stage: "Baby",
          type: "Data",
          digivolution: ["tsunomon"],
          image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/88-punimon.jpg"
        },

        {
          id: "yuramon",
          name: "Yuramon",
          stage: "Baby",
          type: "Data",
          digivolution: ["tanemon"],
          image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/123-yuramon.jpg"
        },
      ],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    blueEgg() {
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(intraining[0].image))

    },
  },

})
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
:root {
  --white-color: #ffffff;
  --baby-yellow: #FFF141;
  --training-blue: #19E0FA;
  --rookie-gold: #AD9B11;
  --champion-pink: #FA198C;
  --ultimate-violet: #AD095D;
}

#yellow-background {
  background-color: var(--baby-yellow);
  height: 50vw;
}

#yellow-background h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <div class="container" id="yellow-background">
    <h1>In-training Stage</h1>
    <div class="image">{{baby[2].image}}</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

Comment: `<img :src="baby[2].image" />` is enough no? Then `v-for` on it. As [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74767006/8816585).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```html
<div class="container" id="yellow-background">
  <h1>In-training Stage</h1>
  <img :src="baby[2].image" alt="">
</div>
```

More details can also be found here: [there is a nested "src": "", in json object which i intend to display on my page, how can i select it using Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74766738/there-is-a-nested-src-in-json-object-which-i-intend-to-display-on-my-page/74767006#74767006)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Kissu, this was the solution:

HTML

```
 <div class="container" id="yellow-background">
   <h1>In-training Stage</h1>
   <img :src="baby[2].image" alt="">
 </div>
```